# How to fix System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialize?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-code

So I am so close to finishing what I need for school, but I have this last problem and I do not know how to fix it and I have looked everywhere and nothing seems to help.  Here is the code below as follows.
Here is the code as well that might be helpful for you to help me with this issue that I am having because I for the life of me cannot figure it out at all.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.WebForm1" 
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title> Progress Reports </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
  ProviderName= "System.Data.SqlClient" 
   SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM ProgressReport">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
[InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand() +7151089
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection 
outerConnection) +32
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection 
outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, 
DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +315
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource1 retry) +128
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +265
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +133
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] 
datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, 
CommandBehavior behavior) +182
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 
maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +180
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +123
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments 
arguments) +2947
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, 
DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +26
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +134
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +107
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +58
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +227
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +227
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean 
includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3671
```

Comment: To provide assistance you need to show relevant code.

Comment: where you define the connection string

Comment: The SqlDataSource has a property named "ConnectionString" which you haven't assigned a value to. See these examples
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource?view=netframework-4.8#examples

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a connection class Where you can write

```
private static string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost/MSSQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YourDB; Integrated Security=false";
```

This should be A global initialization for the whole class. Inside your class when you want to execute any SQL operation you can use something like

```
public void LoadData()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand(cmdString, connection))
               { 
               connection.Open();    
               // query        
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              } 
            
        }
```

When you are done with this class you can close the connection

```
Close() or Dispose()
```

This is a very old and common solution. On the other hand, if you have a

> web.config

Then you can use

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbConnect" connectionString="data source=PCNAME\MSSQLSERVER01; initial catalog=DBNAME; 
         integrated security=FALSE" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Then you can use dbConnect as your connection configuration.

```
string connectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnect"].ConnectionString;
```

Follow this link for more details [Details](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/various-ways-to-specify-connection-string-in-Asp-Net-web-app/)

Comment: I am not quite sure about the dbConnect with web.config.  So I add the connection string in that, but where do I put the string connectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnect"].ConnectionString;

Comment: If don’t have web.config you don’t have to use it